# Paging in sql server for top level query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server I have an Employee table and an Address table.
An Employee can have many Addresses.
I want to get the first 10 Employees with their Addresses.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  Employee e 
  LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.EmployeeID = e.Id
WHERE
  a.Street LIKE '%a%'
  AND e.Name LIKE '%bob%'
ORDER BY e.Id 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

If each employee has 2 addresses associated with it I will get 10 rows but only 5 employees.
How do I get the 10 employees I want?

Comment: Probably a dumb question and been answered before but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT ea.*
FROM (SELECT e.*, a.*,  -- should select the columns you really need
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.id) as seqnum
      FROM Employee e  JOIN
           Address a
           ON a.EmployeeID = e.Id
      WHERE a.Street LIKE '%a%' AND e.Name LIKE '%bob%'
     ) ea
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY e.Id ;
```

Comment: I think that might work. I'm going to try it with the much more complex query I have and get back to you.